# What are the replacements for the smart pointers that existed before Rust 1.0?

Tags: rust

I'm updating some old Rust code that used smart pointers and other memory management code that was deprecated and removed prior to the version 1 release.

Is there a direct replacement for the likes of the old smart pointers or is it better to use the likes of Box for allocating memory?

I have code such as (and this is very much simplified!)

```
struct my_rectangle {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    length: i32,
    breadth: i32,
}

fn allocate_rect() {
    let x: ~my_rectangle = ~my_rectangle{x: 5, y: 5, length: 25, breadth:15};
}
```

and

```
fn firstMethod() {
    let memblock: @int = @256;
    secondMethod(memblock);
    println!(“%d”,  *memblock);
}

fn secondMethod(memblock: @int) {
    let secMemblock: @int = memblock;
}
```

This works fine prior to 1.0 but now fails to build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `~T` by `Box<T>`, and `~[T]` by `Vec<T>`. The `@T` smartpointers can be replaced by `Rc<T>`, and `@[T]` by `Rc<RefCell<Vec<T>>>`. Be careful not to create cycles with `Rc<T>`, there is no cycle-collector anymore. If the code you wish to update looks anything like the code in your examples, then I would recommend not using pointers at all. `~T` (or `Box<T>`) in particular tends to be overused, and can often be replaced by a simple `T`.

Answer (score 6):

`~T` was changed to [`Box<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html). `~expr` should now be `Box::new(expr)`.

`@T` was removed; it was meant to be a pointer to a garbage-collected object, but that was never really the case. The standard library provides reference-counted pointer, [`Rc<T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and [`Arc<T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), that should cover most use cases.

Rust has changed quite a bit until 1.0. You might want to read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) to get yourself up to date.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers cover the principles, so here's your specific examples updated:

```rust
struct MyRectangle {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    length: i32,
    breadth: i32,
}

fn allocate_rect() {
    Box::new(MyRectangle {
        x: 5,
        y: 5,
        length: 25,
        breadth: 15,
    });
}
```

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

fn first_method() {
    let memblock = Rc::new(256);
    second_method(memblock.clone());
    println!("{}", memblock);
}

fn second_method(memblock: Rc<isize>) {
    let sec_memblock = memblock;
}
```

1. `int` and `uint` became `isize` and `usize`, respectively. However, you shouldn't just blindly transform these - often times a specific sized integer is better.
2. Types and traits use `CamelCase` while functions use `snake_case`.
3. There's no need for many type annotations; type inference is very good.
4. `println!` no longer uses printf-style format strings. Instead, there are placeholders like `{}` and `{:?}` corresponding to traits like `Display` and `Debug`.
5. There's no need to dereference the argument passed to `println!`.
6. Calling `second_method` would transfer ownership of the argument and then you couldn't print it. You need to call `clone` to increment the reference count and pass the cloned value to the function.

I second the recommendation to evaluate if you really need to box many of these values. In some cases, you may be able to accept a reference or perform a copy of the value (which should be cheap).