# What is ~const?

Tags: rust

This is `Option`'s `contains()` method signature:

```
pub const fn contains<U>(&self, x: &U) -> bool
where
    U: ~const PartialEq<T>
```

What exactly is that `~const`?

Comment: Looking through resent content, it looks like '~' has been deprecated?

Comment: Related? https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-revamped-const-trait-impl-aka-rfc-2632/15192

Comment: @J.S.Orris there was pre-1.0 syntax where `~T` and `~expr` were special syntax for `Box<T>` and `Box::new(expr)`, see the answers here: [What are the replacements for the smart pointers that existed before Rust 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38410247/2189130) That's probably what you've seen as deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a new-ish experimental syntax for the [`const_trait_impl`](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-revamped-const-trait-impl-aka-rfc-2632/15192) feature.

Remember that the std library can use experimental features even in the stable channel.

Basically, this allows you to implement a trait full all const functions and use it in a const context.
Something like this:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo(&self);
}

struct A;

impl const MyTrait for A {
    fn foo(&self) { /* is is a const function! */}
}

struct B;

impl MyTrait for B {
    fn foo(&self) { /* is is NOT a const function */}
}

const fn test<X>(x: &X)
   where X: ~const MyTrait
{
    x.foo();
}
```

Now a call to `test(&A)` can be done in a const context while a call to `test(&B)` cannot. Without the `~const` it would never be a const function:

```
static THE_A: () = test(&A); //ok
static THE_B: () = test(&B); //error: B does not implement MyTrait constly
```

In the case of the `Option` implementation, `Option::contains()` is const if the implementation of `T as PartialEq` is const.

Comment: this is a rather ~feature

Comment: Looks like this will be/has been removed. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/110395